# How do I override the WPF GroupBox disabled (i.e. Gray) color for its header?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have followed the advice of previous answers for setting a global GroupBox style that includes a HeaderTemplate. The style works great for when the affected GroupBox objects are enabled. When the affected GroupBox objects are disabled, I can only get the border color to change. I don't want the default Gray color when the GroupBox objects are disabled. My GroupBox style is shown below:

```
    <!-- This is the color brush I am trying to set on the header text -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="moDisabledFGColor" Color="DarkBlue" Opacity="0.5" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource moFGColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource moFGColor}" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}}, Path=Header}" FontWeight="Bold"
                                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}}, Path=Foreground}" />
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderText" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource moDisabledFGColor}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource moDisabledFGColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource moDisabledFGColor}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Your style seems to work fine for me.  The groupbox title is the correct color - DarkBlue with 0.5 opacity.  You are not talking about the stuff inside the groupbox right?

Comment: For me, the style only seems to work on the groupbox title when the group is enabled. When the groupbox is disabled, the groupbox title goes gray. I want the border (which does change) and the title to match. The default (enabled) color I have set is:
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="moFGColor" Color="DarkBlue" />

Comment: There has got to be something else going on then, because using your style as you have it above works perfectly for me.  Is this a simplified version of a larger style?  I don't see that the DataTemplate.Triggers are doing anything.  The style triggers seem to be enough. - For me at least.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I'll try my style without the DataTriggers. I'll also try disabling some other global styles/resources that may be affecting my groupbox objects.

Comment: might also be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744748(v=vs.110).aspx